# How to get POST data in codeigniter3 controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, codeigniter-3

I am using frontend angularjs and beckend codeignitor(3).
I want to post data in backend controller.
But i cant get data.

Here is my html-

```
 <form>

            <fieldset class="form-group">
            <h3>Get data of your table</h3>
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Select coloumn value</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="table.table_column" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="table coloumn values">
                <small class="text-muted">Please enter valid data.</small>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Enter Table Name</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="table.table_name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter Table Name">
                <small class="text-muted">Please enter valid table name.</small>
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Where</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="table.table_where" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Where">
                <small class="text-muted">Please enter valid value</small>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Value</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="table.table_value" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Table Value">
                <small class="text-muted">Please enter valid value</small>
              </fieldset>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitForm(table)">Submit</button>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Here is my angularjs controller function-

```
$scope.submitForm = function(table) { 
    $http.post("http://localhost/DatabaseApp/welcome/getData/",table)
        .success(function(response) {$scope.data = response});
}
```

Here is my codeignitor function-

```
 function getData()
{  

        $table_column   =       $this->input->post('table_column');
        $table_name =           $this->input->post('table_name');
        $table_value    =       $this->input->post('table_value');
        $table_where    =       $this->input->post('table_where');

    print_r($table_name);

}
```

So if someone can help me out I'd be grateful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Give the names for inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course you can't get data with $_POST Array because angular $http send request data as string streamed so you should use :

```
$data = file_get_content("php//input");
$data = json_decode($data);
  $table_column   =       $data->table_column;
   $table_name =           $data->table_name;
   $table_value    =       $data->table_value;
    $table_where    =       $data->table_where;
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

1) You should to add `method="POST"`  and  `action="~/nameController/nameAction"` in form tags.

2) Give names for your inputs.

```
<form method="POST" action="~/nameController/nameAction">
<input type="text" name="exampleInputPassword1"/>
 <!--You code here-->

</form>
```